# what exactly does the @with annotation do? (Play Framework)

Tags: syntax, annotations, playframework

I don't quite understand what the @with annotation does.

in the Play framework site, it is written :

> we can annotate the controllers using the @With annotation to tell
>   Play to invoke the corresponding interceptors

is it the same as inheritance ? will it invoke @before of the given class parameter ? what exactly does it do ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way I can describe it, is that it kind of gives you multiple inheritance at your controller level for your interceptors. Interceptors being the `@Before`, `@After` annotations.

You could therefore

- define a controller that dealt with your secure area `@Before` annotations
- define a controller that dealt with injecting your static data for shared actions using `@Before`

you could then define a controller or controllers that contained all your actions, and use the `@With` annotation to make use of the two controllers described above. It means you can separate your code out cleanly, and not have to rely on inheritance to execute the `@Before` annotations.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have 2 controllers:

- `A` has `@Before` or other controller action injection annotations,
- `B` get annotated with `@With(A.class)`

All those injection actions defined in `A` will be effective when calling `B`'s action methods.

It's kind of inheritance. However with inheritance you can extend at most one class. But you can do `@With({A.class, Z.class, ...})`

Comment: If i understand you correctly, in B class i can call any method that is in A class (implicitly) ?

Comment: No, just intercepters ((at)Before, (at)After, (at)Final etc) will work