# Playframework documentation for annotations

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

During the process of implementation using Playframework, I have come across a few scenarios that I would like to apply some cross-cutting logic for different controllers and actions.

Like this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369208/what-exactly-does-the-with-annotation-do-play-framework), I would like to know more about different annotations. However, my search with the document didn't give me any detailed information. 
From [this page](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaActionsComposition), I learnt a few available annotations, but non of them were explained thoroughly.

I checked the API for java, but didn't find anything useful either. Is the source only place to find my answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create your own interceptors, there's a guide to this here: http://www.objectify.be/wordpress/?p=374