# @With annotation in Play Java

Tags: java, playframework, annotations, playframework-2.5

I don't understand the meaning of `@With` annotation in Play Java.
We have [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369208/what-exactly-does-the-with-annotation-do-play-framework) in StackOverflow that seems to be Play1, not Play2.
And in Play's document of the latest version, I saw this example.

```
@With(VerboseAction.class)
public Result verboseIndex() {
    return ok("It works!"); }
```

What does it mean?    In the above case, what is the difference between with the annotation and without the annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obvious that @With is using for composing Actions:

```
public class VerboseAction extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {
    public CompletionStage<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) {
        Logger.info("Calling action for {}", ctx);
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

You can compose the code provided by the action method with another `play.mvc.Action`, using the `@With` annotation:

```
@With(VerboseAction.class)
public Result verboseIndex() {
    return ok("It works!");
}
```

So, when `verboseIndex` will be called, at first method `call` of `VerboseAction` will be called. So, in this example, first the `Logger.info` will write some info message, and then later `ok` response will be completed.

Comment: I see.  But, `verboseIndex` is a method whereas `VerboseAction` is a class.  So, to me it is strange.  How do you explain?

Comment: yes, because Action is a decorator for the action method call.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  What do you mean by the "decorator"?  You explained that when the method `verboseIndex` is called, the `VerboseAction` is also called.   But in the most detailed level, I assume a method should be called.  So, actually what is called when `verboseIndex` is called?   The method `call` within the `VerboseAction`?

Comment: @KazuyaTomita, yes

Comment: And the return value of `delegate.call` method is `CompletionStage<Result>` which can be `Result`, so for example after executing the method `verboseIndex`, the `call` method in a certain Action class will be executed.   Am I right?

Comment: I have checked your update.   In the javadoc comment, `Executes this action with the given HTTP context and returns the result.` is the comment toward `call` method of the Action class.  In the above example we are discussing now, when the `delegate.call` is called, that means the `ok("It works!)` is called?  So, here we add just the log writing by using `@with` annotation?

Comment: @KazuyaTomita, in the example above - yes, just logging.